# Convert Images to PDF without using any Third Party Converter

Tags: php, image, pdf, yii, converters

Is this possible? Because as what I have researched, most are using converters. How can I convert images to PDF using only PHP (Yii 2.0 framework, specifically) without the help of any converter software?

In my web application, user is to fill up a form and attach an image. I would like to convert that attached image to a PDF file.

Anyone might be of help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am not sure if a source code is needed here. So if you need it, just let me know.

Comment: Do you have any issues with [ImageMagick PHP extension](http://php.net/imagick)? It is very common php extension

Comment: ImageMagick does installation right? We discourage such because it might be a hassle when our system is used on other operating systems. Tried FPDF but still fixing some issues.